# Exclude folder(s) in VS 2019 Find in Files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

...yes I know this is an old tune, but I would like to make it specific to the newest tool, and also put in context and emphasize the issue. Doing this in hope that soon we will have a working solution.

**Context**

In many web projects there are zillions of library files like jquery, bootstrap etc. To make it worst, there are the .min. siblings, what are one liner, so editor killers. Usually we do not want to search within those files and it is a productivity killer, especially if one accidentally clicks on a found .min. file which freezes the editor when opens...

**Question**

Is there any way to define and exclude folders in a project or solution when using VS 2019 Find in Files?

Answer (score 0):

If you press the button to the right of the "Look In" drop down:

[image: Look In control of Find in Files]

you can select a set of folders to use. This set of folders can be saved for future use (ie. the lack of ability to include a parent folder and then exclude a child is not as bad as it could be).

Comment: I think the lack of exclude is really bad. We must add all folders in the solution except (in my example) /wwwroot/lib This could be dozens. What's worst, we must remember to update this named set every time when we add a folder to the solution... But the worst with this facility is that stores the "named folder set" computer wide, and with _absolute_ paths. So 1) we must create this for each solution (repetitive) then save with distinguished names and pollute the Look in dropdown with dozens of sets. 2) Must do it on all computers, or copy (how?) and hope paths on the other comp. identical